# Кто может объяснить принцип работы

Tags: java

Есть код

```
public class Solution {
public void someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    int lock1 = obj1.hashCode();
    int lock2 = obj2.hashCode();
    Object firstLock = lock1 > lock2 ? obj1 : obj2;
    Object secondLock = lock1 > lock2 ? obj2 : obj1;
    synchronized (firstLock) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
        synchronized (secondLock) {
            System.out.println(obj1 + " " + obj2);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isNormalLockOrder(final Solution solution, final Object o1, final Object o2) throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (o2) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (o2) {
                solution.someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks(o1, o2);
            }
        }
    });
    thread1.start();
    System.out.println(thread.getState());
    System.out.println(thread1.getState());
    return Thread.State.BLOCKED.equals(thread1.getState());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Solution solution = new Solution();
    final Object o1 = new Object();
    final Object o2 = new Object();

    System.out.println(isNormalLockOrder(solution, o1, o2));

}
}
```

Задание было такое

Реализуй логику метода `isNormalLockOrder`, который должен определять:

соответствует ли порядок `synchronized` блоков в методе `someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks` — порядку передаваемых в него аргументов.

В случае, если сначала происходит синхронизация по `o1`, а потом по `o2`, метод должен вернуть `true`.

Если наоборот — `false`.

Вопрос вот в чем, задание принято, то есть правильно выполнено, но, оно как я понял не работает у меня корректно, да и вообще не понятно. Кто может пояснить, почему блокируется только `synchronized` (`o2`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, для проверки правильности на тесте добавьте в метод `someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks(Object obj1, Object obj2)` строку  `System.out.println("must be "+ (obj1.hashCode() > obj2.hashCode()));`

Вы увидите, что иногда результат работы вашего метода проверки будет неверен.

Во-вторых, если вы сказали потоку `thread.start()` это еще совсем не значит, что он успел стартануть *до того как* начал выполняться код в основном потоке. Запросто может быть ситуация когда он вообще стартанет *после того как* основной поток завершит работу. 
Даже может быть такая ситуация, что оба новых потока *вообще не успеют начать работу* до того как закончит работу основной поток. 
Поэтому лучше снова перерешать задание.

Так как время вышло вот вариант правильного ответа:

```
public static boolean isNormalLockOrder(final Solution solution, final Object o1, final Object o2) throws Exception {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            solution.someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks(o1, o2);
        }
    });

    synchronized (o2) {
        synchronized (o1) {
            thread1.start();
            //спим чтобы второй поток попал в состояние ожидания - он не может захватить ни o1 ни o2
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } //отпускаем монитор o1
        //спим чтобы второй поток попробовал выполнить работу после того как o1 был отпущен
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //теперь поток thread1 ждет, но вопрос захватил ли он монитор o1
        //если он его захватил - значит порядок правильный
        //если нет - обратный

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (o1) {
                    System.out.println("o1 не захвачен потоком thread1");
                }
            }
        });
        thread2.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000); //ждем чтобы thread2 стартанул и попытался захватить o1

        return Thread.State.BLOCKED.equals(thread2.getState());

    }

}
```

Comment: Вот согласен, потому что я смотрел ответы, где решение правильное, валидатор не принимал :) Мое же решение приняло, хотя я менял местами параметры и по сути у меня должно было на выходе false быть, у меня все равно true. Я данное решение тоже взял из подсказак, но у меня просто вопрос, зачем два раза делать synchronized по o2. В первом потоке и втором. Как я понял, главный поток main блокирует o1. Если есть возможность, можете объяснить поблочно? Мне нужно один раз понять, а я все читаю статьи, а вникнуть не могу :(

Comment: В коде же выше вообще неизвестно кто заблокирует первым o2. Главный поток вообще ничего не блокирует. (Всего тут три потока. )

Comment: Код проверки  работает неправильно. поэтому не вижу смысла глубже в нем разбираться. Сейчас он вообще непонятно что проверяет. Даже между   командами      System.out.println(thread.getState()); и 
        System.out.println(thread1.getState()); могут быть изменение ситуации - так что они вообще ничего не показывают. Надо писать новый код с чистого листа. Можете на словах сформулировать алгоритм проверки?

Comment: Скорее всего логика проверки должна быть такая: 1) блокируем второй объект 2) пока блокируется второй объект, надо вызвать проверяемый метод из второго дополнительного потока 3) когда проверяемый метод отработал (частично, так как он не сможет залочить оба объекта), то возможны 2 ситуации - а) проверяемый метод остановится на попытке блокировки первого объекта или б) проверяемый метод остановится на попытке блокировки второго объекта. Отличия будут  в том успел ли заблокироваться первый объект или нет вторым потоком. Именно это надо проверить.

Answer (score 0):

Даже не знаю как объяснить, первоначально при получение задания код такой

```
public class Solution {
public void someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    synchronized (obj1) {
        synchronized (obj2) {
            System.out.println(obj1 + " " + obj2);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isNormalLockOrder(final Solution solution, final Object o1, final Object o2) throws Exception {
    //реализуйте метод
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Solution solution = new Solution();
    final Object o1 = new Object();
    final Object o2 = new Object();

    System.out.println(isNormalLockOrder(solution, o1, o2));

}
```

}

а задание вот:

Определяем порядок захвата монитора

Реализуй логику метода isNormalLockOrder, который должен определять:

соответствует ли порядок synchronized блоков в методе someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks — порядку передаваемых в него аргументов.

В случае, если сначала происходит синхронизация по o1, а потом по o2, метод должен вернуть true.

Если наоборот — false.

Требования:

1. Метод isNormalLockOrder должен возвращать true в случае, если синхронизация в методе someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks происходит сначала по объекту o1, а потом по o2.

2. Метод isNormalLockOrder должен возвращать false в случае, если синхронизация в методе someMethodWithSynchronizedBlocks происходит сначала по объекту o2, а потом по o1.

3. Метод isNormalLockOrder НЕ должен быть приватным.

4. Класс Solution НЕ должен быть объявлен с модификатором final.

Comment: ответил выше - добавил код в старый ответ

Comment: большое спасибо за объяснение, стало немного ясно и понятно. А то читаю читаю и не могу никак понять. Очень уж тяжело дается многопоточность :(